# Project selected ruby version does not match ruby -v using asdf-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asdf-vm

I switched to a new computer and set up a whole development environment from start. One of the changes was trying to use asdf instead of rvm. Sadly when trying to run `rails s` or `rails c` on one of the projects I have im running into:

`Your Ruby version is 2.7.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3`

2.6.3 is the version specified by Gemfile indeed, the same is in `.tool-versions` file and `.ruby-version`.

My lack of understanding comes from me not having ruby 2.7.1.

```
asdf list =>
ruby
  2.6.3
```

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

```
which ruby
/home/kkp/.asdf/shims/ruby
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just as I posted I suddenly remembered to run
`gem install bundler`
and off we go